# PhpMailer with office365 work fine in localhost and not in the server

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer

So i'm using PhpMailer to send emails from office365.

my probelem is that in localhost it sends emails correctly

but when i uploaded the script to the server i get an error.

here is my code :

```js
<?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';


require_once 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

$mail_ilyes = new PHPMailer(True);
$mail_ilyes->isSMTP(); // Paramétrer le Mailer pour utiliser SMTP 
$mail_ilyes->SMTPAuth = true; // Activer authentication SMTP
$mail_ilyes->SMTPSecure = 'tls';


$mail_ilyes->Host = 'smtp.office365.com'; // Spécifier le serveur SMTP
$mail_ilyes->Username = 'myemail@bomarecompany.com'; // Votre adresse email d'envoi
$mail_ilyes->Password = 'password'; // Le mot de passe de cette adresse email



$mail_ilyes->Port = 587;
$mail_ilyes->setFrom('dev@bomarecompany.com', 'Support Bomarecompany'); // Personnaliser l'envoyeur
$mail_ilyes->addAddress("ilyes.bourouba7@gmail.com"); 
$mail_ilyes->addReplyTo('supportsav@bomarecompany.com', 'Replay'); // L'adresse de réponse

$mail_ilyes->IsHTML(true); 
$mail_ilyes->Subject = 'register Code';
$mail_ilyes->CharSet = 'UTF-8';



$mail_ilyes->Body = 'vvvv';
// $mail_ilyes->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
$mail_ilyes->SMTPDebug = 1;

if(!$mail_ilyes->send()) {
   echo 'Erreur, message non envoyé.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo 'Le message a bien été envoyé !';
}

?>
```

and that's the error i get:

```html
2021-03-31 19:34:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO sav.streamsystem.com
2021-03-31 19:34:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2021-03-31 19:34:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-03-31 19:34:59
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, this means there is a difference between the environments you're running in, rather than anything the scripts are doing.

This exact issue (QUIT immediately after STARTTLS) is [described in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure). It would help if you set `SMTPDebug = 2` rather than 1 because then you will see what the server is saying. The most likely explanation is that your server's CA certificate bundle is outdated (but your local one is not), which is causing a verification failure of the mail server you're connecting to. So the fix is most likely to update your server.

You should really search before posting, since [this question has been asked and answered many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+server+localhost).